# How to align drawable w.r.t. horizontally centered Text in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have the Textview as Follows

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numberLookup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blue"
    android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#5b5b5b"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Now I want the drawable which is a "dot" image to align only some distance to left.
I am getting with this code is "dot" at extreme left of textview.

I am getting is this:

```
        <<drw>        This is text            >   
        <<drw>  This is larger or huge text   >
```

What I want is

```
        <      <drw>  This is text            >   
        <<drw>  This is larger or huge text   >
```

Can I do this ?

Comment: post an image showing what you want to achieve

Comment: <drw> is a drawable which is size of textview height,
text is centered horizontally, I want drawable to be positioned w.r.t. text

Comment: and you dont want to use any other views like a FrameLayout?

Comment: How to use it? .I am new to Android

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put ImageView and TextView  whether in to LinearLaout or RelativeLayout

Code sample

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="blah blah blah" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not infront of my work pc so can only test in the morning:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:text="your text here" />

</LinearLayout
```

Comment: You could potentially even try it without the layout_gravity's as long as the LinearLayout has a gravity="center"